# Excluding results from SQL query based on entries in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database that look like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab_closure_states`
(
state_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
lab_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
period_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date DATE NOT NULL,
state BOOL NOT NULL
)  ENGINE = MYISAM 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 
COLLATE = utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lab_appointments`
(
appointment_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
created DATETIME NOT NULL,
user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
lab_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
period_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
date DATE NOT NULL,
class_size INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
comment TEXT NOT NULL,
lab_is_closed BOOL NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 
COLLATE = utf8_bin;
```

Is it possible to select all appointments for a given user where the state is not FALSE? The complication I have is that I may not necessarily have a `lab_closure_state` entry for each `lab_appointment` that exists.
Thanks

Comment: Would you skip entries without lab_closure_state entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to mean a strict answer to your question text but rather to answer the question header:

```
SELECT *
FROM lab_appointments root
LEFT OUTER JOIN lab_closure_states satellite 
    ON  satellite.lab_id = root.lab_id
    AND satellite.state = 0
WHERE 
    satellite.state_id IS NULL
```

Approach shown above gives you an opportunity to link multiple satellite tables in your query and build complex filter criterias by simply placing `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` in `WHERE` statement.